# Push a field to the end of every subArray of a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP Multidimensional associative array structured in this way:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [serverid] => 1
        [ip] => localhost
        [name] => Server1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [serverid] => 2
        [ip] => localhost
        [name] => Server2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [serverid] => 3
        [ip] => localhost
        [name] => Server3
    )
```

Now I need to push at the end of every subArray this new field with this value:

```
['page_url'] = base_url('/server/id/') . $server['serverid'];
```

Where `$server['serverid']` is the **serverid** field relative to every single subArray.

I've tried with this cycle but seems it doesn't work:

```
$result = $query->result_array();
foreach($result as $server) {
        $server['page_url'] = base_url('/server/id/') . $server['id'];
}
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: To modify in foreach add & beforу varname foreach($result as &$server) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the subarray when iterating trough an array in a foreach, you have to pass the variable as a reference using `&`.

If you change your code to the one below, it should work as you'll be changing the original array item instead of a created copy.

```
foreach($result as &$server) {
        $server['page_url'] = base_url('/server/id/') . $server['id'];
}
```

Comment: Great solution, I had not considered that I was copying the values and not modifying the original array.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a temporary copy of the subarray, which you're changing and then throwing away on the next iteration:

```
foreach ($result as $server) {
        $server['page_url'] = base_url('/server/id/') . $server['id'];
}
```

You want to change the original array. Something like this:

```
foreach (array_keys($result) as $index) {
        $result[$index]['page_url'] = base_url('/server/id/') . $result[$index]['id'];
}
```

If you know you haven't mucked with the indexes in `$result` you could also just do:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($result); $index++) {
```